# Use SQL query in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel-5

this is my sql Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT batch_job_instance.JOB_NAME, MAX(batch_job_execution.CREATE_TIME) AS CREATED_TIME,  batch_job_execution.END_TIME, batch_job_execution.STATUS FROM `batch_job_execution` INNER JOIN batch_job_instance ON batch_job_execution.JOB_INSTANCE_ID = batch_job_instance.JOB_INSTANCE_ID WHERE batch_job_execution.CREATE_TIME LIKE '%2016-12-05%'  GROUP BY batch_job_instance.JOB_INSTANCE_ID ORDER BY MAX(batch_job_execution.CREATE_TIME) DESC
```

my Question, how i use that query in laravel? i am new in laravel, can someone help me? i need this for my project Thanks :)

Comment: are you using eloquent models?

Comment: yes, i using eloquent model, so how i can put that sql query to laravel with eloquen model?

Answer (score 0):

You can run this SQL query as ot is if you had problem in converting in laravel format.

You can use :

```
 DB::select(DB::RAW(your_sql_query)):
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can create a function within your model and query the data using the bellow format

public static function getJobs()
{
    $jobs = DB::table('batch_job_execution')
        ->select(
            DB::raw('
                     DISTINCT batch_job_instance.JOB_NAME, 
                     MAX(batch_job_execution.CREATE_TIME) AS CREATED_TIME,
                     batch_job_execution.END_TIME,
                     batch_job_execution.STATUS 
                     '
            )
        )
        ->join('batch_job_instance', 'batch_job_execution.JOB_INSTANCE_ID', '=', 'batch_job_instance.JOB_INSTANCE_ID')
        ->where('batch_job_execution', 'LIKE', '%2016-12-05%')
        ->groupBy('batch_job_instance.JOB_INSTANCE_ID')
        ->orderBy(DB::raw('MAX(batch_job_execution.CREATE_TIME)'),'DESC')
        ->get();
//        ->toSql();

    return $jobs;
}
```